# Force .Net program to use '.' as decimal symbol

Tags: c#, vb.net, floating-point, globalization

I'm trying to get a string formatted float number (e.g. "3.14") from a COM port.

I used `Convert.ToSingle()` but it threw exception "Input string was not in a correct format" And while debugging, I found that double, float and decimal numbers are separated by '/' instead of '.'; for example 3.14 was 3/14.

My system language is English, but date and time formats are in Persian (Windows 10). In Persian, we use / instead of . as the decimal symbol.(۳/۱۴ = 3.14)

Is there any way to make program independent of system regional settings and force it to always use '.' as decimal symbol?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the string containing the number looks like `"3/14"`. If so, the problem isn't with Convert or the various Parse methods, but either with the data the Arduino program sends or with the decoding of the string. Maybe check which character set is being used when the Arduino encodes the number as a string.

Comment: Correction: After reading your question more carefully, it seems like the Arduino program is using the Persian standard for encoding the number as a string (`/`), while your program on the PC side expects the English convention to be used (`.`).

Comment: Exactly the opposite! Arduino sends 24.71 but visual studio wants 24/71. The problem is from windows regional settings. Decimal symbol is set to "/" and it makes problem with program. I can change windows regional setting to correct it for myself but what if the users system use "/" for decimal symbol like mine? I want the program to be independent of windows regional setting.

Comment: Try this to understand my problem: `float example = Convert.ToSingle("3.14");` it runs ok. now go to control panel> clock and region> region> additional settings... and change decimal symbol from `.` to `/`. Now the code makes error. Now, change "3.14" to "3/14". It works again.

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Convert.ToSingle` will attempt to convert an object to a floating-point number based on the system's region settings, as you have already noticed.

In order to reliably convert a string that is, for example, in US-English format, you can provide an additional argument of the type `IFormatProvider` to the method.

```
string text = "3.5";
IFormatProvider culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
float number = Convert.ToSingle(text, culture);
```

The result stored in `number` be `3.5`, i.e. the number halfway between three and four, independent of your system settings. For example, the above code works as expected on my computer, even though it's set to the German (de-DE) region, which represents the same number as `3,5`.

See also the [documentation of `Convert.ToSingle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToSingle_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) for details.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!